# Self Executing function doesnt work?

Tags: javascript

I have the code :

```
function (i)
{
    alert(i);
}(3);
```

I don't understand why I don't see the alert.

What does this syntax mean?

And why this code:

```
( function (i)
{
    alert(i);
}(3))();
```

Does work?

**What is the difference?**

What Am I Missing?

Comment: On FireFox: "SyntaxError: function statement requires a name."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first snippet will be interpreted as **function declaration**, which needs a name and your function does not have one. So this will result in an error.

Surrounding the function definition with parenthesis makes the function to be interpreted as **function expression** which doesn't need a name, so it is valid JavaScript.

Though it seems you are making two invocations there. It should either be

```
(function(i){ alert(i); }(3));
```

or

```
(function(i){ alert(i); })(3);
```

Typically you can have function expression either in parenthesis (everything is evaluated as expression there) or at the right side of an assignment expression (`var a = function...`).

See [Section 13 of the ECMAScript 5 specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_13):

> *FunctionDeclaration* :
>           **function** *Identifier* ( *FormalParameterList*<sub>opt</sub> ) {*FunctionBody*}
>
> *FunctionExpression* :
>          **function** *Identifier*<sub>opt</sub>  (*FormalParameterList*<sub>opt</sub> ) {*FunctionBody*}

Comment: Made quick test case, easier to demonstrate in there: http://jsfiddle.net/xMZbc/ :)

Comment: @Felix Kling http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/ the code there says `link.onclick = function (num) {
   return function () {
    alert(num);
   };
  }(i);`   ... so why is it working there ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You mean the inner or the outer function? The outer because it is an assignment expression, and the inner because of `return`.

Comment: @Felix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979184/javascript-self-executing-supposed-to-work

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Actually that was what I'm trying to tell you. If you have an assignment, the right hand side is *always* interpreted as expression, hence you don't need parenthesis....

Answer (score 0):

The `()`-operator is responsible for executing a function, therefore a function expression which is wrapped by `()` is exectued immediately.

Comment: This is not correct. Parenthesis have a different meanings, depending on their position and context. Put after a function reference, they execute that function, but in any other case they act as grouping operation. Take `var foo = (5 + 3) * 2;`. There is no function execution involved here.