# Javascript Syntax: Anonymous Self Calling Functions

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self Executing function doesnt work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978219/self-executing-function-doesnt-work)

In Javascript, why does

```
function() { console.log('hello'); }();
```

give an error, but

```
function() { console.log('hello'); }()
```

not?

Edit: some answers state that both give syntax errors in Firefox, but this does not seem to be the case in either Chrome or a Node.js REPL. Additionally,

```
(function() { console.log('hello'); }());
```

seems to work fine in Firefox.

Comment: In get an error in both cases...

Answer (score 2):

Actually both of those are SyntaxErrors.

You need to wrap parens around the anonymous function so it can be properly parsed.

```
(function(){alert('eyo')})();
```

This defines the function and immediately invokes it. It's not syntactically valid to define a function and invoke it without 'forming' the function by wrapping parens around it.

Good explanation here: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

> Fortunately, the SyntaxError “fix” is simple. The most widely accepted
>   way to tell the parser to expect a function expression is just to wrap
>   in in parens, because in JavaScript, parens can’t contain statements.
>   At this point, when the parser encounters the function keyword, it
>   knows to parse it as a function expression and not a function
>   declaration.

Comment: Good job, but if you work at twitter you can also use `!` instead of parens.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() { console.log('hello'); })();
```

You must invoke some function, in this case is "()"

No, any [Syntax errors](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s19/sh/c2439c47-db9f-4222-81fe-1b8770f90c00/d83d34db57ed315b972cdc8f48613052)

Comment: That's not really an explanation. *edit*: The OP has parenthesis after the function definition, shouldn't this count as "call"?

Comment: Yes; this doesn't seem to answer the question at all.

Comment: Also you can do this (function() {console.log('hello');}())

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox, both lines generate the same error:

> SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

To fix this, simply add parentheses:

```
(function() { console.log('hello'); })();
```

The error is probably raised because it indicates a syntax error:

```
function (value) {
    return value * value;
}
```

It's obvious that the function name is missing, and that no anonymous function was intended.

Therefore, anonymous functions always have to occur as expressions, e.g. to assign a variable:

```
var a = function() { };
```

Otherwise, you need the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

an anonymous function that is followed by `()` is essentially you saying "immediately call this function" but your syntax is not correct because without the wrapping parents, the `()` doesn't attach to anything *(there is an exception, that if you set your anonymous function equal to a variable, its ok, but you didn't do that... see comments).*

so it must be like this: `( function(){} )()`

think of it like this:

```
1. ( someExpressionReturnsFunction )(2)
2. is now: aFunction(2)
```

Comment: That's not completely true. `var foo = function() { return 'bar'; }();` works perfectly.

Comment: @FelixKling lol I am loving your comments.

Comment: @Esailija: I take it as a compliment :D

Comment: he is the king, afterall

Answer (score 0):

As the others pointed out, there's a difference in assignment vs. an expression

Self-executed functions are functions that were turned into expressions:

```
// self-executed due to both being an expression, no function declaration.
!function(foo) { console.log('test', foo); }('first');
(function(foo) { console.log('test', foo); })('second');

// long-hand examples of normal usage without expression conversions.
var bar = function(foo) { console.log('test', foo); };
bar('third');
```

You can only pass through arguments with the least parens "()" afterwards if the thing before is either a callable already-declared function or an expression.

edit:// I added the negotiator example, because that will cause the following keyword being converted in an expression. expressions always return true or false.